# How to show there is no continuous trace operator from $W^{k,2}(R^m)$ to $W^{k,2}(R^{m-1})$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

For positive integer k, how to show that there is no continuous trace operator mapping from $W^{k,2}(R^m)$ to $W^{k,2}(R^{m-1})$?

I want to prove this by contradiction, but have no idea what to do next.  My first thought is to construct a sequence of functions in $C^{\infty}(R^m)\cap W^{k,2}(R^m)$ say $f_n$ which converges to f, then to show that the sequence $g_n = Tf_n$ doesn't converge to $Tf$ in $W^{k,2}(R^{m-1})$.

Update:
Suppose that there exists such a continuous trace operator $T$.
By the fact that $W_{0}^{k,2}(R^m) = W^{k,2}(R^m)$，for a function $f$ in $W^{k,2}(R^m)$, we can find a sequence of functions $f_n$ in $C^{\infty}_{c} (R^m)$ converges to $f$. Then $Tf_n \to Tf$. Since $Tf_n = 0$ for each $n$, $Tf = 0$.

My main problem is that I am not sure how to show $Tf = 0$ is not true for every $f \in W^{k,2}(R^m)$.

Any assistance will be appreciated

Comment: Can you prove this when $k=0$? Perhaps that may help in seeing how to treat the case of general $k$ (starting with $m=1$ if necessary).

Comment: @ktoi, Sorry, I made a typo here.  k must be some positive integer.